# ServiceStack ServerEvents authentication configuration

Tags: authentication, servicestack

I'm trying to use JWT authentication with ServiceStack ServerEvents to ensure that all users are authenticated but I can't find how to configure server events to do this. I assume that this works in the default configuration since it's not mentioned in the docs how to get it working, only that it does, which would mean that something in my configuration has disabled/broken this feature but I can't work out what.

On the server side the setup in Configure() is pretty simple.

```
this.Plugins.Add(
    new AuthFeature(
        () => { return new AuthenticatedSession(); },
        new IAuthProvider[] { jwt, perpetualJwt }
    )
    {
        IncludeAssignRoleServices = false,IncludeRegistrationService = false
    }
);

this.Plugins.Add(
    new ServerEventsFeature
    {
        StreamPath = ApiHost.EventSystemRoot +"-stream", // /request/event-stream
        HeartbeatPath = ApiHost.EventSystemRoot + "-heartbeat",
        UnRegisterPath = null,
        SubscribersPath = null,
        LimitToAuthenticatedUsers = true,
        IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30),
        HeartbeatInterval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20),
        NotifyChannelOfSubscriptions = true,
    }
);
```

the jwt and perpetualJwt providers are JsonWebTokeynAuthProviders (handle bearer token jwt) and I've got these working with standard servicestack api requests so I have confidence that their function is correct, however they may not be getting called.

To connect the client I use code like this:

```
this.directBoardClient = new JsonServiceClient(this.boardUrlTextBox.Text)
{
    BearerToken = this.boardTokenTextBox.Text
};
this.directBoardEvents = new ServerEventsClient(this.boardUrlTextBox.Text.AppendPath("ueib", "request"))
{
    OnMessage = boardEvents_OnMessage,
    OnCommand = boardEvents_OnCommand
};
this.directBoardEvents.ServiceClient=this.directBoardClient;
this.directBoardEvents.Start();
```

When i call start i get a 401. If i don't require auth or i omit the serverevents client the directBoardClient can make calls that require auth successfully.

I think that the auth feature isn't being called when i'm connecting to the stream endpoint and that my moving the events endpoints may have disturbed something but i can't identify what that is. Can anyone help identify what i can do to fix this or suggest further debugging steps?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `ServerEventsClient.ServiceClient` isn't used for establishing the Server Events connection, only its [CookieContainer is shared](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.Client/ServerEventsClient.cs#L186) which will allow you to Authenticate with the `ServiceClient` to establish an [Authenticated Session](http://docs.servicestack.net/sessions).

If you're using a JWT AuthProvider you can [send it inside a Cookie](http://docs.servicestack.net/jwt-authprovider#sending-jwt-using-cookies) so it gets sent with client Web Requests. Otherwise you can try adding the JWT Token using the `EventStreamRequestFilter` which gets executed before establishing the Server Events connection, e.g:

```
new ServerEventsClient(...) {
    EventStreamRequestFilter = req => req.AddBearerToken(jwt)
}
```

Alternatively I [just added support](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/commit/7adcf67555552ff18bd61a5e3142646ab6d4d102) for `ResolveStreamUrl` which will let you modify the URL used to establish the Server Events connection which will also allow you to add the JWT Token to the QueryString as [seen in the JWT TypeScript ServerEventsClient example](http://docs.servicestack.net/jwt-authprovider#send-jwts-in-http-params):

```
var sseClient = new ServerEventsClient(BaseUrl, ["*"], {
    resolveStreamUrl: url => appendQueryString(url, { "ss-tok": JWT }),
    handlers: {
        onConnect: e => { 
            console.log(e.isAuthenticated /*true*/, e.userId, e.displayName);
        }
    }
}).start();
```

The change also lets you modify the `EventStreamPath` independently from the `BaseUri` which was previously assumed to be `{BaseUrl}/event-stream`.

> ResolveStreamUrl + EventStreamPath is available from v5.0.3 that's now [available on MyGet](http://docs.servicestack.net/myget).

This requires that your JWT AuthProvider to accept JWT Tokens via the QueryString which you can enable in ServiceStack's JWT AuthProvider with:

```
new JwtAuthProvider {
    AllowInQueryString = true
}
```