# Server Events Client - Getting rid of the automatically appended string at the end of the URI

Tags: c#, servicestack

I am new to the Service Stack library and trying to use the Server Events Client. The server I'm working with has two URIs. One for receiving a connection token and one for listening for search requests using the token acquired in the previous call.
I use a regular JsonServiceClient with digest authentication to get the token like so:

```
public const string Baseurl = "http://serverIp:port";

var client = new JsonServiceClient(Baseurl)
{
    UserName = "user",
    Password = "password",
    AlwaysSendBasicAuthHeader = false
};

//ConnectionData has a string token property
var connectionData = client.Get<ConnectionData>("someServices/connectToSomeService");
```

And then use this token to listen for server events. Like so:

```
var eventClient =
    new ServerEventsClient($"{Baseurl}/differentUri/retrieveSearchRequests?token={connectionData.Token}")
    {
        OnConnect = Console.WriteLine,
        OnMessage = message => Console.WriteLine(message.Json),
        OnCommand = message => Console.WriteLine(message.Json),
        OnException = WriteLine,
        ServiceClient = client, //same JsonServiceClient from the previous snippet
        EventStreamRequestFilter = request =>
        {
            request.PreAuthenticate = true;
            request.Credentials = new CredentialCache
            {
                {
                    new Uri(Baseurl), "Digest", new NetworkCredential("user", "password")
                }
            };
        }
    };

Console.WriteLine(eventClient.EventStreamUri); // "/event-stream&channels=" is appended at the end

eventClient.Start();
```

The problem with the above code is that it automatically appends "/event-stream&channels=" at the end of my URI. How do I disable this behavior?

I have tried adding the following class

```
public class AppHost : AppSelfHostBase
{
    public static void Start()
    {
        new AppHost().Init().Start(Baseurl);
    }

    public AppHost() : base(typeof(AppHost).Name, typeof(AppHost).Assembly)
    {
    }

    public override void Configure(Container container)
    {
        Plugins.Add(new ServerEventsFeature
        {
            StreamPath = string.Empty
        });

        Plugins.Add(new AuthFeature(() => new AuthUserSession(),
        new IAuthProvider[] 
        {
            new DigestAuthProvider()
        }));
    }
}
```

and called Start on it, before calling the above code, but still no luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ServerEventsClient` is only for listening to ServiceStack SSE Stream and should only be populated with the `BaseUrl` of the remote ServiceStack instance, i.e. not the path to the `/event-stream` or a queryString.

See this previous answer for [additional customization available](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48363048/85785), e.g. you can use `ResolveStreamUrl` to add a QueryString to the EventStream URL it connects to:

```
var client = new ServerEventsClient(BaseUrl) {
    ResolveStreamUrl = url => url.AddQueryParam("token", token)
});
```

If you've modified `ServerEventsFeature.StreamPath` to point to a different path, e.g:

```
Plugins.Add(new ServerEventsFeature
{
    StreamPath = "/custom-event-stream"
});
```

You can change the `ServerEventsClient` to subscribe to the custom path with:

```
client.EventStreamPath = client.BaseUri.CombineWith("custom-event-stream");
```

> ResolveStreamUrl + EventStreamPath is available from v5.0.3 that's now [available on MyGet](http://docs.servicestack.net/myget).

Comment: It seems like setting EventStreamPath does not update the EventStreamUri property on ServerEventsClient object

Comment: @AliZahid ok should be done now from [this commit](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/commit/5c2f6614df10d7aab298c460cca78c9ea2f40384) this change is now available on MyGet. You'll need to [clear your NuGet packages cache](http://docs.servicestack.net/myget#redownloading-myget-packages) to download the latest version.