# ServiceEventsClient only receive the last line of event data

Tags: c#, servicestack

We have a SSE server push the events like below:

```
...
event: event_id
data: AQAAAAAAKTUMAQAAAWuY4NWAAAAAAAAAAwcAAD9IAAAAAAApNQ0BAAABa5jlaWAAAAAAAAADAQAA
data: PVQAAAAAACk1DgEAAAFrmOVpYAAAAAAAAAMDAAA/SAAAAAAAKTUPAQAAAWuY5WlgAAAAAAAAAwUA
data: AEE8AAAAAAApNRABAAABa5jlaWAAAAAAAAADBwAAPuQAAAAAACk1EQEAAAFrmOn9QAAAAAAAAAMB
data: AAA88AAAAAAAKTUSAQAAAWuY6f1AAAAAAAAAAwMAAD7kAAAAAAApNRMBAAABa5jp/UAAAAAAAAAD
data: BQAAQNgAAAAAACk1FAEAAAFrmOn9QAAAAAAAAAMHAAA+5AAAAAAAKTUVAQAAAWuY7pEgAAAAAAAA
data: AwEAAD24
...
```

Two questions:

1. When we use ServerEventClient, we can only receive the last line of event data "AwEAAD24"
2. How to change EventStreamPath query Param when client gets auto reconnection. We need to send a "from" param to query new data from SSE server. Otherwise the SSE server will still push old data to client.

The example code:

```
public void testSSE() {
            var client = new ServerEventsClient(SSEServerUri) {
                EventStreamPath = streamUri + queryParam,
                OnConnect = con => Console.WriteLine(con.Data),
                OnHeartbeat = () => Console.WriteLine("heartbeat"),
                OnMessage = e => Console.WriteLine("message data: " + e.data),
                OnException = exp => printerror(exp.Message)
            };
            client.Start();
            Thread.Sleep(Timeout.Infinite);
        }
```

result:

```
...
message data: AwEAAD24
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you're using a custom SSE Server instead of [ServiceStack's Server Events](https://docs.servicestack.net/server-events) implementation which ServiceStack's [Server Event clients](https://docs.servicestack.net/server-events#server-event-clients) are designed to work with which relies on a number of opinions like calling a periodic heartbeat endpoint, subscribe/unsubscribe endpoints and only a single `data` payload per SSE frame, instead of the multiple ones shown in your example.

Basically if you're not using a ServiceStack Server Events implementation you're going to run into interoperability issues from using ServiceStack Server Event Clients and you should use a more generic and unopinionated SSE client implementation instead.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. To the re-connection question, can we change the EventStreamPath if reconnection happens?

Comment: @KezhenXi I don't understand the relevance of re-connection, but have a look at [ResolveStreamUrl](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48520913/85785) which lets you modify the EventStreamUri that the clients use to establish the SSE connection, it might do what you need.

Comment: The ResolveStreamUrl and EventStreamPath are working perfectly. Thanks for that. One more question about OnException callback, is it only working for ServiceStack Server Events? We can not catch any errors when there is a network issue after client `start()`. Then there is no new message coming.

Comment: @KezhenXi The `OnException` callback gets fired when there's an error with the HTTP Requests when it establishes an SSE connection, processes heartbeats or data responses. As per my answer ServiceStack's Server Event Clients should only be used for consuming ServiceStack Server Events.