# Subscribe user to a SSE channel in ServiceStack

Tags: c#, servicestack, server-sent-events

I'm trying to figure out how can I subscribe a just-authenticated user to a SSE channel using the ServiceStack's `OnAuthenticated` function.
Here is my actual code:

```
public override void OnAuthenticated(IRequest httpReq, IAuthSession session, IServiceBase authService, IAuthTokens tokens, Dictionary<string, string> authInfo) {
    string subscriptionId = // ???;
    string[] channels = { "mychan1", "mychan2" };

    ServerEvents.SubscribeToChannels(subscriptionId, channels);
}
```

My question is: how can I bind the `subscriptionId` to the just-authenticated user in way to give him\her the subscription to the channels?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You can't subscribe on the behalf of a user in a Session, the client needs to make their own authenticated Server Events connection using the [same Service Client they've authenticated with](http://docs.servicestack.net/csharp-server-events-client#add-authentication-support-to-net-serverevents-client), e.g:

Initialize `ServerEventsClient`:

```
var client = new ServerEventsClient(baseUri, channel=channelName) {
   // Register any handlers...
};
```

Authenticate using the built-in Service Client:

```
client.ServiceClient.Post(new Authenticate {
    provider = "credentials",
    UserName = "user",
    Password = "pass",
    RememberMe = true,
});
```

Start the `ServerEventsClient` to establish an Authenticated Server Events connection:

```
client.Start();
```

Alternatively [see this previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48363048/85785) for examples of establishing authenticated Server Event connctions with different Auth Providers like JWT.

Comment: Thank you mythz, so, from what I can understand there's no way to subscribe a user to a channel from the server side?

Comment: @wizzy the persistent connection needs to be established from the client directly to the SSE /event-stream, so no.