# ServiceStack.ServerEvents: Non-public subscriptions based on logged in user - how to structure and use SSE?

Tags: servicestack

I have read all the docs regarding Server Side Events on ServiceStack, as well as search SO and googled about it, but I havent yet found an answer to:

*How to structure SSE, for use when there is no public stream/channel that we broadcast data to. Instead, each individual user should subscribe to his own channel and no other users should ever be allowed to access that channel in any way.*

I am considering using the `ServerEventsFeature` `OnCreated` or `OnSubscribe` events, and throwing an Exception if they are trying to subscribe to a channel that they are not allowed to subscribe too, like so:

```js
internal class ServerSideEventsAlfa : ServerEventsFeature
    {
        private AuthCache _authCache;
        private ICoreLogger _logger;

        internal ServerSideEventsAlfa(ICoreLogger logger, AuthCache authCache)
        {
            _authCache = authCache;
            _logger = logger;

            OnConnect = (sub, par) =>
            {
                OnSubscriptionConnect(sub);
            };
            OnCreated = (sub, req) =>
            {
                OnSubscriptionCreated(sub, req);
            };
            OnSubscribe = (sub) =>
            {
                logger.LogInfo(this, $"SSE sub: {sub.SubscriptionId}");
            };
            OnUnsubscribe = (sub) =>
            {
                logger.LogInfo(this, $"SSE unsub: {sub.SubscriptionId}");
            };
        }

        private void OnSubscriptionConnect(IEventSubscription sub)
        {
            _logger.LogInfo(this, $"New SSE connect: {sub.SubscriptionId}");
        }

        private void OnSubscriptionCreated(IEventSubscription sub, IRequest req)
        {
            _logger.LogInfo(this, $"New SSE created: {sub.SubscriptionId}");
            Customer customer = GetCustomerOrThrowIfNotLoggedIn(req);
            sub.ConnectArgs["username"] = customer.Username; 
            sub.ServerArgs["username"] = customer.Username;

            if (sub.Channels.Length != 1 || sub.Channels[0] != customer.Username)
            {
                throw HttpError.Forbidden("You are not allowed to join");
            }
        }

        private void OnSubscriptionSubscribe(IEventSubscription sub, IRequest req)
        {
            _logger.LogInfo(this, $"SSE sub: {sub.SubscriptionId}");
            Customer customer = GetCustomerOrThrowIfNotLoggedIn(req);
            if (sub.Channels.Length != 1 || sub.Channels[0] != customer.Username)
            {
                throw HttpError.Forbidden("You are not allowed to join");
            }
            sub.ConnectArgs["username"] = customer.Username;
            sub.ServerArgs["username"] = customer.Username;
        }

        private Customer GetCustomerOrThrowIfNotLoggedIn(IRequest req)
        {
            Customer customer = _authCache.GetAuthenticatedCustomer(req);
            if (customer == null)
                throw HttpError.Unauthorized("Not authorized");
            return customer;
        }
    }
```

Q1: Is this a correct approach?

Q2: I use HTTP headers to send two keys, which determines if the user is authenticated. In the C# ServerSideEvents Client, I tried using the `ServerEventsClient.ServiceClient.AddHeaders(...)` but on the server, those headers never appeared there. They do however seem to be present on the client side:
[image]
Any ideas on this one?

Comment: Three downvotes; id like to know why? Its better to leave a comment, and then the question might be modified if need to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do they need to be subscribed to a unique channel, why can't you use [IServerEvents](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/1036956603d1288ec908aca6f8720a2c352b2a73/src/ServiceStack/ServerEventsFeature.cs#L1211) to send messages directly to a User via either:

```
void NotifySubscription(string subscriptionId, string selector, object message, string channel=null)

void NotifyUserId(string userId, string selector, object message, string channel = null)

void NotifyUserName(string userName, string selector, object message, string channel = null)

void NotifySession(string sessionId, string selector, object message, string channel = null)
```

No other User is going to receive messages that are directed to a specific User.

> In the C# ServerSideEvents Client, I tried using the ServerEventsClient.ServiceClient.AddHeaders(...) but on the server, those headers never appeared there.

The persistent Server Events Connection uses it's own HttpWebRequest connection that can be modified using `EventStreamRequestFilter`, e.g:

```
client.EventStreamRequestFilter = req => req.Headers.Add(...);
```

Comment: Well, because I am not using the built-in session thingie in ServiceStack; its stateless, so the headers contain the necessary auth info, and I validate every request; thus, I am not using the built in session-stuff, and thus, I cant use most of those methods. However, the big question isnt that =) The question is: why is the headers not present at the server?

Comment: @Ted it doesn't use the `ServiceClient` for the SSE connection, if you want to modify the EventStreamConnection you can use the `EventStreamRequestFilter` on the `ServerEventsClient`.

Comment: Aha, thats a bit confusing. I found another post where u answer, when I searched for that filter: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48360068/servicestack-serverevents-authentication-configuration/48363048#48363048

Comment: I think it would be a good move to add header support directly to those Server event clients...

Comment: @Ted That is exactly the API to add Headers or otherwise Customize the EventStream WebRequest via a Single Filter, we have no intentions of adding different properties for each customization available esp. for a feature like this that's used so infrequently.

Comment: Alright, please add the EventStreamRequestFilter  as an answer to this question, and I will mark it as the answer. Also, you dont like to use different channels; any specific reason? Its kinda clean and clear, less chance of giving out info on a channel where all users are?